# MySQL on a laptop for remote workers - MyISAM keeps corrupting

Tags: mysql, corruption, sql

We have an application that is used by remote, mobile workers.  It intalls WAMP (Server2Go) on a laptop and uses MySQL to store data locally.  All tables are MyISAM.  Once a day, the workers sync the database to our central server via HTTP scripts that query the data and post it to our site.

The problem is that many of these laptop database tables are corrupting continually.  It appears that MySQL acts like it saves the information (I don't get any query errors), but the table gets corrupt.  I have to repair the table constantly (which removes several rows of data in the process).

Does anyone have any ideas about how to work around this problem?  Would it be wise to switch to InnoDB on the laptops?  How about a different database system altogether.  I have looked at MySQL Embedded, but it appears to be the same engine as the regular MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

If this is happening on more than one machine I can only see it as a bug in your application, which clearly isn't reporting all errors. Remember, there is a lot more to acessing MySQL than just the queries. e.g. Are you properly freeing the results after running any query which returns results?

Unless you actually need the other stuff that WAMP installs, about which you've given no indication, consider removing it completely and installing just the latest MySQL. Changing DB engines is really unlikely to fix the problem, as there is nothing to indicate that is where the problem is.